# Size limit in Google Big Table

Tags: google-app-engine

I found out that in Amazon Simple DB, an attribute can have a maximum size of 1024 bytes. So I am thinking to move to Google App Engine and use Google Big Table.

Is there any such restriction on Google Big Table as well?

I am trying to make a blogging platform on Google Big Table where the StringFields will be more than 1024 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An entity in App Engine can be up to 1MB once encoded into the wire-format. Individual properties have no specific limit, but indexed properties must be 512 bytes or shorter. Since you don't want to index the body of a blog post as a single entry anyway, this won't be a problem for blog entries.

You might want to check out my series on [writing a blogging system on App Engine](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/10/Writing-a-blog-system-on-App-Engine).

Tangentially, note that the App Engine datastore is not raw Bigtable; it's a layer built on top of Bigtable, which provides a lot of extra capabilities.

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities.html) says that the Text type can be used to store strings up to 1 Mb (not indexed).